# Adafruit PiTFT capacitive touch not showing on i2c

Tags: pitft, adafruit

I recently picked up one of the overhang versions of the pitft 2.8 capacitive touch and tried the easy install with the 640x480 mirror of HDMI in pixel/xwindows. But I was not getting capacitive touch. I'm just getting into digging on it, but I've gotten to the point of realizing it is not showing up on i2c.

I was trying to look at the kernel overlay, but it's failing to convert.

from dmesg:

```
[ 13.905526] edt_ft5x06 1-0038: touchscreen probe failed
[ 13.905574] edt_ft5x06: probe of 1-0038 failed with error -121
[ 13.942129] fbtft: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[ 13.954309] fb_ili9340: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[ 13.955669] fbtft_of_value: buswidth = 8
[ 13.955683] fbtft_of_value: debug = 0
[ 13.955691] fbtft_of_value: rotate = 90
[ 13.955699] fbtft_of_value: fps = 25
[ 14.162441] graphics fb1: fb_ili9340 frame buffer, 320x240, 150 KiB video memory, 4 KiB buffer memory, fps=25, spi0.0 at 32 MHz
```

#### things I have tried:

```
$ i2cdetect -l
i2c-1 i2c bcm2835 I2C adapter I2C adapter

$ i2cdetect -y 1
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 a b c d e f
00: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --

$ dtc -I dtb -O dts /boot/overlays/pitft28-capacitive.dtbo -o pitft28-capacitive.dts
pitft28-capacitive.dts: Warning (unit_address_vs_reg): /__local_fixups__/fragment@3/__overlay__/pitft@0: node has a unit name, but no reg property
pitft28-capacitive.dts: Warning (gpios_property): /fragment@3/__overlay__/pitft@0:dc-gpios: Could not get phandle node for (cell 1)
pitft28-capacitive.dts: Warning (gpios_property): /__fixups__:gpio: property size (117) is invalid, expected multiple of 4
dtc: livetree.c:565: get_node_by_phandle: Assertion `generate_fixups' failed.
Aborted
```

config files:

```
$ cat /etc/udev/rules.d/95-ftcaptouch.rules
SUBSYSTEM=="input", ATTRS{name}=="EP0110M09", ENV{DEVNAME}=="*event*", SYMLINK+="input/touchscreen"
SUBSYSTEM=="input", ATTRS{name}=="generic ft5x06*", ENV{DEVNAME}=="*event*", SYMLINK+="input/touchscreen"

$ cat /etc/udev/rules.d/95-stmpe.rules
SUBSYSTEM=="input", ATTRS{name}=="*stmpe*", ENV{DEVNAME}=="*event*", SYMLINK+="input/touchscreen"

$ cat /etc/udev/rules.d/95-touchmouse.rules
SUBSYSTEM=="input", ATTRS{name}=="touchmouse", ENV{DEVNAME}=="*event*", SYMLINK+="input/touchscreen"
```

relevant stuff from config.txt

```
dtparam=i2c_arm=on
dtparam=spi=on
dtparam=i2c1=on

dtoverlay=pitft28-capacitive,rotate=90,speed=32000000,fps=20
dtoverlay=pitft28-capacitive,touch-swapxy=true,touch-invx=true

hdmi_cvt=640 480 60 1 0 0 0
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Do you know if the probe fails because there's nothing in i2c, or there's nothing in i2c because the probe failed?

Comment: Not sure as I have not had time to play with it recently. I was setting it up for an octoprint on a new 3d printer and opted to get a 7" official pi touch screen when initial tests didn't work. But I hope to get time to play with that one again before too long.

Comment: I thought I had a capacitative touch screen, but it's resistive touch (option 1 in the pitft setup script instead of option 4). Now I've done that it's working just fine.